# Ansible - ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'docker_swarm'

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm

I created a role to initialize docker swarm with the code bellow

```yaml
---
- name: Init docker swarm
  docker_swarm:
    state: present
  register: init_swarm
```

I also created another role for the docker installation:

```yaml
---
- name: install libs
  apt:
    name:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg
      - lsb-release
      - python3-pip
      - virtualenv
      - python3-setuptools
    state: present
    update_cache: yes

- name: install docker gpg key
  apt_key:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    state: present

- name: Add docker repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
    state: present

- name: install docker
  apt:
    name: 
      - docker-ce
      - docker-ce-cli 
      - containerd.io
    state: present

- name: install jsondiff
  pip:
    name: jsondiff  
    state: present
    
- name: install docker-compose
  apt:
    name: docker-compose
    state: present
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'docker_swarm'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/matheuslino86/projetos/fc-ansible/roles/docker_swarm_manager/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Init docker swarm
  ^ here
```

I tried to install docker swarm collection by executing `sudo ansible-galaxy collection install docker_swarm`

Comment: `I tried to install docker swarm collection by executing sudo ansible-galaxy collection install docker_swarm` <= why `sudo` ? You want to install the collection as the user which is running the playbook.

Comment: I can't run ansible commands without sudo

Comment: Otherwise I would get an error, maybe that's happen because of the way that I installed that

Comment: `pip install ansible` is the only officially supported install method and will install ansible for your current user (or your current virtualenv if you created one).

Comment: And running any ansible command with sudo is definitelly not the intended use.

Comment: In anyways the bigger problem is that I can't manage to use this "docker_swarm" module with ansible.